# Can the arc from a Tesla coil or plasma from a high powered plasma orb be redirected with an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, lightning

So I was wondering if you could use electromagnets to redirect the electric arcs created by a Tesla coil or the plasma arcs from a high powered plasma ball so you can control the direction it is going.  I tried looking at lightning but lighting itself is too complicated and the forces of Nature won’t let me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

An electron beam in a cathode ray can be deflected by a magnet, but the best way to deflect an arc would be to put a grounded conductor near-by.  A near-by electromagnet would probably have the same effect (and don't hold it in your hand).